# Errno::ENOTTY Inappropriate ioctl for device when trying to send file to SFTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, sftp, ioctl

I am using a rails webapp and trying to send an xml file to a sftp server, using the following script:

```
Net::SSH.start(SFTP_HOST, sftp_user, {:port => SFTP_PORT, :password => sftp_password}) do |ssh|
ssh.sftp.connect do |sftp|
  sftp.upload!( measurements_xml_file_path( meas ).to_s ) do |event, uploader, *args|
    case even
    when :open
      puts "Starting upload"

    when :finish
      puts "Finished upload"
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

Nevertheless, I am always get an error `"Errno::ENOTTY ... Inappropriate ioctl for device"`. Any help how to fix this error?

Comment: I solved a more or less similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69796705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IOCTL is a Device Input and Output Control meaning the error comes from a poorly formed or misconfigured command being sent to the server.

It could be the PTY issue described in a comment as the server does not have a terminal output and SFTP is attempting to display the progress bar.

Alternatively, it could be a result of a poorly formed command being sent to the server as the output of `measurements_xml_file_path( meas ).to_s` is unknown and possibly incorrect. SFTP takes two arguments, one for the input file on the host and one for the output file on the server.

[class Net::SFTP](https://net-ssh.github.io/net-sftp/)

```
To upload a single file to the remote server, simply specify both the local and remote paths:

uploader = sftp.upload("/path/to/local.txt", "/path/to/remote.txt")
```

Comment: "message": "Inappropriate ioctl for device",
  "backtrace": [
    "/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-5.2.0/lib/net/ssh/prompt.rb:45:in `noecho'",
    "/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-5.2.0/lib/net/ssh/prompt.rb:45:in `ask'",
    "/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-5.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/password.rb:68:in `ask_password'",
    "/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-5.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/password.rb:21:in `authenticate'",                       Received this error for wrong password.